# How to style a PhoneTextBox in windows phone 8?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I need to style a PhoneTextBox ("clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit")

```
    <toolkit:PhoneTextBox x:Name="txtName" InputScope="Text" PlaceholderText="name"/>
```

I am using PlaceHolderText instead of Hint property. I was able to find default styles for applied for Hint. But not for PlaceholderText. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PhoneTextBox` doesn't have `PlaceholderText` property. It exists on `TextBox` for `Windows Runtime`. The similar property for `PhoneTextBox` is `Hint`, which I currently suggest you to use.

If you need to style\template PhoneTextBox control, you can always find original style in `Windows Phone Toolkit` source code ([Generic.xaml](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.WP8/Themes/Generic.xaml)).

Comment: Thanks! But I don't find Hint for the PhoneTextBox. Instead I get PlaceholderText.

Comment: I have used WPtoolkit.Kinnara.

Comment: @Meee It changes everything :) Here you go: [Generic.xaml](https://github.com/Kinnara/WPToolkit/blob/custom/Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.WP8/Themes/Generic.xaml) Check 1489th line.